# Find all unique xml first nodes under a parent node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm an xsl n00b and trying to find all unique xml nodes under the `<section>` node

Here's my code:

```
<section>
   <books>
     <book>
       <title>Child 44</title>
       <author>Thomas Rob Smith</author>
       <price>5.00</price>
     </book>
     <book>
       <title>Atlas Shrugged</title>
       <author>Ayn Rand</author>
       <price>7.00</price>
     </book>
   </books>
   <cds>
     <cd>
       <title>A Passage in time</title>
       <band>Authority Zero</band>
       <price>10.00</price>
      </cd>
   </cds>
</section>
```

Here is my desired output:

```
books
cds
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're going to have to make some effort... we will not just write code for you.

Comment: A little clarification... I don't know what nodes are below the section node, the nodes will be unique nearly every time. So I want to do something like /section/*/@value

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution, using the most efficient grouping method for XSLT 1.0. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kElByName" match="/*/*" use="name()" />

 <xsl:template match=
  "/*/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kElByName',name())[1])]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),'&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<section>
    <books>
        <book>
            <title>Child 44</title>
            <author>Thomas Rob Smith</author>
            <price>5.00</price>
        </book>
        <book>
            <title>Atlas Shrugged</title>
            <author>Ayn Rand</author>
            <price>7.00</price>
        </book>
    </books>
    <cds>
        <cd>
            <title>A Passage in time</title>
            <band>Authority Zero</band>
            <price>10.00</price>
        </cd>
    </cds>
</section>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
books
cds
```

**Do note**: The **[Munchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml)** is used. This is probably the most efficient grouping method for XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
/section/*[not(name(.)=name(preceding-sibling::*)) and not(name(.)=name(following-sibling::*))]
```

Comment: This method can't be used when testing for other things than implicit casted values, because `fn:name()` (and any other function by the way) will take only the first node in the node set.

Comment: @Alejandro: thinking about it, you are of course correct, thanks for the comment :)